# How do I convert this c++ function to c#?

Tags: c#, c++

I tried using the online converter but it didn't work out.

The C++ function is as below. I want it's equivalent in c#.

```
//! Save the SURF features to file
void saveSurf(char *filename, vector<Ipoint> &ipts)
{
  ofstream outfile(filename);

  // output descriptor length
  outfile << "64\n";
  outfile << ipts.size() << "\n";

  // create output line as:  scale  x  y  des
  for(unsigned int i=0; i < ipts.size(); i++) 
  {
    outfile << ipts.at(i).scale << "  ";
    outfile << ipts.at(i).x << " ";
    outfile << ipts.at(i).y << " ";
    outfile << ipts.at(i).orientation << " ";
    outfile << ipts.at(i).laplacian << " ";
    outfile << ipts.at(i).scale << " ";
    for(int j=0; j<64; j++)
      outfile << ipts.at(i).descriptor[j] << " ";

    outfile << "\n";
  }

  outfile.close();
}
```

I think ofstream is streamwriter or may be filestream.

Comment: It appears to me as if I have committed some crime by asking this question. Marius Bancila answered this question in 6 minutes and I was able to resolve it in next 15 minutes. I really believe that there was no need for so many downvotes and also there was no need to consider it off-topic. It is a programming question involving two different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("file.txt"))
{
    writer.WriteLine("64");
    // etc.
}
```

Or async:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("file.txt"))
{
    await writer.WriteLineAsync("64");
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent of "outfile << ipts.Count << "\n";"?

Comment: You'd probably use a `List<T>` instead of of `std::vector`, so that would be `WriteLine(list.Count)`.

Comment: You answered my question in 6 minutes. I implemented your solution in 15 minutes. Testing took another 10 minutes. And the problem is resolved. Thank you very much,